# When creating mex in MATLAB: error C3861: 'fmax': identifier not found

Tags: c++, mex

I am creating a mex file in MATLAB from a .cpp file which is written in VS 2010. I receive this error in MATLAB: error C3861: 'fmax': identifier not found. 
I replace fmax with just max and everything works. I am including  in my .cpp file. 
A while ago, I have done exactly the same with another code with no error! 
How to get around this problem?

Does anybody know how std::max is different than max of "windows.h"?

Comment: probably it was not with VS 2010?

Comment: It was. It is. I created it using this same computer with this exact VS that I'm using now. But, hmm...the MATLAB was a different version. Is the behavior of "max" exactly the same as "fmax" on floating points? I don't want to lose precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fmin` and `fmax` are a C99 features. Microsoft doesn't fully support the C99 standard. You can use `std::max` and `std::min` from standard *algorithm* library instead, after all you write C++ program.

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Comment: Is it std::max(x,y) ? I receive an error doing this.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Any precision/accuracy lost compared to fmax? How is it different than "max" in windows.h?

Comment: There shouldn't be any lost precision, but please do contact your compiler, sir.